# Passing ArrayList to another activity Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I get this error:

[image: Error]

at line where I want to put ArrayList..

What am I doing wrong?

**My code:**

```
    List<Integer> skatlice = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    ...

    if (cases[position] == 1) {
       myIntent2 = new Intent(Game.this, Skatle.class); 
       vrednostskatel = 1;
       myIntent2.putExtra("vrednostskatel", vrednostskatel);

       skatlice.set(0, 1);
       myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", ArrayList<Integer> skatlice);

       startActivity(myIntent2); 
       overridePendingTransition(R.layout.mainfadein, R.layout.splashfadeout);
}
```

Comment: you should remove ArrayList in this line
    `myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", ArrayList<Integer> skatlice);`
it would look like
`myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", skatlice);`

Comment: @Apple Then I get this error: The method putIntegerArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<Integer>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Integer>)

Comment: I think you should cast your List into ArrayList, you should put back the the ArrayList<Integer> but enclose it with open and close parenthesis. it would look like this  
`myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", (ArrayList<Integer>) skatlice);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect, change

```
myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", ArrayList<Integer> skatlice);
```

to

```
myIntent2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", (ArrayList<Integer>) skatlice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a mutable list (ArrayList) from your  immutable list skatlice. Use this:

```
intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("skatlice", new ArrayList<>(skatlice));
```